# Input date Jan 03 but returns Jan 02, why?

Tags: java, date

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String opDate = "Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 MSK 2006";
    String date = convertDate(opDate, "yyyyMMdd");
            
    System.out.println("opDate: " + opDate);
    System.out.println("date: " + date);
}

public static String convertDate(String opDate, String dateFormat) {
    Date date = new Date();
                                                    //  Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 MSK 2006
    SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    
    try {
        date = dateParser.parse(opDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception = " + e.toString());
    }
    
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Russia/Moscow"));
    String strDate = df.format( date.getTime() );
    
    return strDate.trim();
}
```

out:

> opDate: Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 MSK 2006
>
> date: 20060102

Why does it return Jan 02?

Comment: Did you check the time and timezone? I assume the date is returned as GMT and thus might be Jan 2nd 21:00:00.

Comment: Might have something to do with the timestamp. Try by defining the opDate string like this:   String opDate = "Tue Jan 03 01:00:00 MSK 2006";  and see if it helps

Comment: Probably something to do with time zones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the fetching of the `"Russia/Moscow"` time zone. The correct zoneinfo ID is `"Europe/Moscow"`. Change the ID, and the problem goes away:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
```

It's unfortunate that `TimeZone.getTimeZone("random rubbish")` returns the UTC time zone rather than letting you know in some way that it's broken.

Comment: `MSK` seems to be parsed fine - the date resolves as 9pm GMT on 2 Jan, which looks correct.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle: Yes, I realized that a while ago and edited - it's the Russia/Moscow which was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Probably due to timezone conversion.
I would suggest you also print the time and the timezone of your resulting date. This is likely to be Jan 2, 23:00 or something.

This happens because you set a different timezone on the `SimpleDataFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

Timezones.

You're specifying midnight on January 3rd **in MSK**.  This is 9pm on the 2nd January in GMT (the likely default timezone).

I can see that you're trying to output in Moscow time as well, but `Russia/Moscow` is not a valid timezone, and the `getTimeZone` call "helpfully" [silently defaults to returning GMT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29).  This then of course doesn't change the time zone of the date when formatting and outputs it as 2 Jan.

If you set the timezone to `Europe/Moscow`, you'll get the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

May it be related to the fact that you're converting dates between two distinct TimeZones?

Answer (score 1):

If you change line:

```
String date = convertDate(opDate, "yyyyMMdd");
```

to:

```
String date = convertDate(opDate, "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

you can see the output of your program:

```
opDate: Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 MSK 2006
date: Mon Jan 02 20:00:00 GMT 2006
```

You are not setting well TimeZone with:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Russia/Moscow"));
```

you need:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
```

Finally there are summer delay of 1h.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 MSK 2006";
        String formatted = formatDateTimeStringTo(strDateTime, "yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);

        System.out.println("opDate: " + strDateTime);
        System.out.println("date: " + formatted);
    }

    public static String formatDateTimeStringTo(String strDateTime, String targetFormat, Locale locale) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d H:m:s zzz u", locale);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(targetFormat, locale);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser);
        // System.out.println(zdt); // 2006-01-03T00:00+03:00[Europe/Moscow]
        return zdt.format(formatter);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
opDate: Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 MSK 2006
date: 20060103
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/QH7efo)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Follow the standard convention to name the timezone:

Ask your publisher to switch to the standard naming convention of the timezone. The [standard naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is Region/City e.g. Europe/Moscow. The two/three/four letter abbreviation for the timezone is error-prone as described in the following text at the [`Timezone` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) page:

> ##### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
> IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their
> use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for
> multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
> Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
> then only recognize one of them.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>